# SQL Server : converting TIME to a number

Tags: sql-server

I need to multiply each row of two columns, let's call them `Cal1` and `Cal2`. `Cal1` is declared as a `FLOAT`, `Cal2` as a `TIME`.

I came to understand that you can not multiply a `TIME` with a `FLOAT`, which makes sense. So I'll have to transform the time (example 04:30:00) to a number I can calculate with (example 4.50).

For example, my current columns:

| Cal1 | Cal2 |
| --- | --- |
| ... | 04:00:00 |
| ... | 05:30:00 |
| ... | 03:30:00 |

I need it to look like this:

| Cal1 | Cal2 |
| --- | --- |
| ... | 4,00 |
| ... | 5,50 |
| ... | 3,50 |

So that I can calculate with it.

Best thing I could think of was to try:

```
SELECT CATS(CAST(Cal2 AS datetime) AS float) * 24
```

The output is showing me the correct numbers, but how do I replace my current Cal2 with these numbers to calculate with it?

Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: `SELECT cast(cast('04:30:00' as datetime) as float) * 24` ?

Comment: Please share more info about what you think is incorrect about your own "Best thing I could think of", see: [DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/BUfBsbqC), or are you not satisfied with [DBFIFFLE2](https://dbfiddle.uk/KH3MWxpG) ?

Answer (score 1):

This looks like you should add a computed column to make use of, something like

```
alter table YourTable 
  add DecimalTime as 
  Convert(Decimal(4, 2), DatePart(hour, cal2) + DatePart(minute, cal2) / 60.0 + DatePart(second, cal2) / 3600.0);
```

Then you can simply use the column `DecimalTime`.

Also note it's *unusual* to use the `float` data type, it's an imprecise data type and *probably* you should be using `Decimal/Numeric`.